# Conditionally derive based on feature flag

Tags: rust

I want to add a feature to my crate that will optionally make certain structs serializable, and in particular, I want to use Serde's custom derive macros. The Serde dependencies are optional and `extern crate` declarations are conditionally included behind the feature.  Consider the following:

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Serialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    a: u8,
    b: u8
}
```

With the feature flag enabled, it all works fine. With it disabled, I get this warning:

```
error: '#[derive]' for custom traits is not stable enough for use. It is deprecated and will be removed in v1.15 (see issue #29644)
```

Is there a way to conditionally include derived traits? I'm using Rust 1.15 stable.

Should I submit an issue for the error message? It seems misleading.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like many other pieces of feature-based conditional compilation, use `cfg_attr`:

```
#[cfg_attr(feature = "example", derive(Debug))]
struct Foo;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Foo);
}
```

With this, `cargo run` will fail to compile as `Debug` is not implemented for `Foo`, but `cargo run --features example` will compile and run successfully.